# "Willing to relocate" option is misleading

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

On my career's profile, If I have the option "willing to relocate" selected, then it makes me sound like I do not live in the United States. What I want is "Willing to relocate within the United States", not "Willing to relocate TO the United States"

I think this is very misleading

Comment: No, employers are not going to be stumped by this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Does it* imply that you are "willing to relocate *to* the United States"?  To me it just indicates that you aren't attached to your *current* location.

The option itself just says "`[X]` I'm willing to relocate". Below, you can indicate locations, on each of which you can check "`[X]` 
I have the legal right to work here immediately" (relieving any potential immigration concerns for potential employers).

What about that makes it sound like you don't live in the United States?

Your location is also written right below your name.  So I'm not sure I see how it could it be any *less* confusing...

Comment: My location is written actually quite small and italicized in Career's 2.0. It took me a second to find it. And by saying "I'm willing to relocate to the US" does it not sound like you are actually living somewhere other than the US? You wouldn't move somewhere that you already are

Comment: @Earlz It doesn't force you to type "to the US" anywhere, does it? If you are willing to relocate to specific locations, type those, otherwise, don't type any (just leave it at "I'm willing to relocate").  Searchers will see that you are willing to relocate, see that you are in US, and you've pretty much got the point across.

Comment: Ah, ok.